# Sumar valores (no contar) en tablas cruzadas con R

Tags: r, group-by, sum, summarise, compilación-cruzada

Miren, llego a lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
TABLA_AÑO_PPV2 <- UNIDO %>% 
   group_by(Año,Diagnostico) %>% 
   summarise(Total=sum(Valor_PPV)) 

TABLA_AÑO_PPV2
```

pero lo que requiero es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en R. Agradecería enormemente su ayuda! No encuentro solución. Mil gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenida  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Lo que estás buscando se logra con `pivot_wider()`: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html